# Confusion matrix of 10 fold cross validation

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to perform 10 fold cross validation for analysing the results of my character recognition project using neural networks in matlab. I know how to calculate the confusion matrix for each fold. But the problem is i dont know how to calculate the confusion matrix averaged over the 10 folds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the confusion matrices for each fold, you can simply sum their values to get the total confusion matrix.

For example, if you had two folds,and the resulting confusion matrices were

```
                     Classifier
                 -----------------
                 Class 1   Class 2
Actual | Class 1      25         3
       | Class 2       6        21

                     Classifier
                 -----------------
                 Class 1   Class 2
Actual | Class 1      23         5
       | Class 2       4        23
```

Then the total confusion matrix is

```
                     Classifier
                 -----------------
                 Class 1   Class 2
Actual | Class 1      48         8
       | Class 2      10        44
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.Got it now.

Comment: A confusion matrix is normally expressed in terms of totals, rather than averages. If you mean you want to average the performance over multiple folds, than you can just average all the elements (i.e. divide all the numbers in the total confusion matrix by the number of folds) but that won't give you any information that's not in the total confusion matrix, and it may bias your numbers if the test sets in each fold aren't the same size.